# Traverse nested list and assign an interdependent value to each element w/o recursion (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, list, nested, non-recursive

I want to dissolve the recursion of the following function because some input data lead to an exceeding recursion depth error.
[Increasing the recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it) is not a solution in the long-run.

```
def foo(x):
    for element in x.elements:
        element.depth = x.depth + 1
        self.foo(element)
```

[List flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python) is not applicable since the original list structure needs to be preserved.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340351/python-iterating-through-list-of-list) uses a generator, containing a recursion though. Does the fact that it is a generator make a difference?

Finally, there is the [stack approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579513/visit-all-elements-in-nested-lists-and-dicts-without-recursion). Here, I am not sure if this is 100% applicable since the interdependence of the to-be-assigned values.

What would be an elegant (Pythonic), non-recursive solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically implementing a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on your data. Your data is graph where each element is a node, and a connection between two elements is an edge.

You can easily replace recursive DFS with a stack DFS by iterating elements and pushing to stack, and keep doing so until stack is exhausted.

Be aware that there might be a [small difference in the ordering of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9201166/572670), but that can be solved easily as well.

The pseudo code for DFS will be:

```
def foo(x):
   s = new stack
   s.push(x)
   while not s.empty()
   e = s.pop()
     for element in e.elements:  # or elements[::-1] for reversed order
          element.depth = e.depth + 1
          s.push(element)
          # if data structure is not a tree, add visited set.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(x):
    stack = [(x,0)]
    while stack:
        node,depth = stack.pop(0)
        node.depth = depth
        stack.extend([(ele,depth+1) for ele in node.elements if ele])
```

I think at least... based on your description